# What could cause 429 errors in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

We have a Google Sheet (implementing Import Range) randomly giving these errors in the developer console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()
```

When this occurs, the sheet loads in HtmlView and is mostly inaccessible. Are there any access rate limits that could be causing this, or is it just a server issue?

Most of the time it seems that the sheet is stable.